# What is wrong with this while loop code in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
def nearest_square(limit):
key=0
while key<=limit:
    i=0
    key=i*i
    i+=1
return key
```

test1 = nearest_square(40)
print("expected result: 36, actual result: {}".format(test1))
will this loop be running for infinite time?

Comment: Did you look at each line of the function? There is a `key` doing nothing, and afterwards, a re-definition of `i` at each iteration. Your question could've been solved had you bothered to put _any_ effort into debugging.

Comment: now the question is correct, i forgot to write "=0" after key

Comment: That's not the only problem with your code...

Comment: whats the other

Comment: A good habit to get in, is to print the values of the variables in question to the console - that would show you that `i` and `key` are not increasing

Comment: @terra9 Did you not read my first comment? I said `i` is being redeclared inside the loop, so `key` always receives the same value, and the `while` loop condition never becomes True, so you iterate infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you initiate your i inside while loop, remove the i to outside, and it will work.

what will happen is your key will be equal to 0 since the variable i will always 0 when you assign the value of key(i trying to increase, but the initialization keep changes the i equal to 0):

```
loop 1:
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1

loop 2
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1

loop 3:
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1

loop 4:
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1

loop 5:
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1

loop 6:
initiate i = 0
key = 0*0 = 0
i = 1
```

and it will keep looping (which will lead to infinite loop)
Btw try to give some spaces at your code, it will significantly help you for more complex code.

Comment: what is wrong with i being initialized inside loop? can you explain

Answer (score 0):

you have defined i inside the while so during each iteration it will be defined.define i outside the while loop like this

```
i=0
while key<=limit:
    key=i*i
    i+=1
return key
```

and i hope u have initialized key before it is used inside while loop.

Comment: if u initialize i inside while loop its value will become zero at the beginning of each iteration

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the indentation right.

You don't need to define 'key'.  In Python your variables will be defined when you initialize them.

Then, in your whole loop you keep seeing i to zero.  That needs to be done before your whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Avinash,
There are several things wrongs with this code:
1.**Indentation** - Your code needs to be indented inside the function
2.**Setting variables** - You have created the variable key but didnt assign any value to it, you need to declare it as the type you are going to use it, in this case integer.
3.**Logic**  - in the loop you set the i variable as 0, so the first stage of k = i*i does nothing... start i as 1(or other nubmer) and put it outside the loop

your code should be more like this:

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    key = 0
    i=1
    while key<=limit:
        key=i*i
        i+=1
    return key
```

Answer (score 0):

**code:**

```
def nearest_square(limit):
    max_val = -1
    for val in xrange(1, limit):
        cur_power = val*val
        if max_val < cur_power and cur_power < limit:
            max_val = cur_power
        if cur_power > limit:
            break
    return max_val

test1 = nearest_square(40)
print("expected result: 36, actual result: {}".format(test1))
```

**output:**

```
expected result: 36, actual result: 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't increasing the value of `i` inside the `while loop`.

Initialize `i=0` before while loop. Working example:

```
def nearest_square(limit):
key=0
i=0
while key<=limit:
    key=i*i
    i+=1
return key
```

`test1 = nearest_square(limit = 40)
print("expected result: 36, actual result: {}".format(test1))`